# Loading multiple .txt files to pandas dataframe with columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read all the .txt files with the below format provided and concat them to a single pandas dataframe.

## sample1.txt

```
ID                                    a123
Delivery_person_ID             VADRES03DEL01
Delivery_person_Age                    24.00
Delivery_person_Ratings                 4.30
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

## sample2.txt

```
ID                                    b123
Delivery_person_ID             VADRES03DEL02
Delivery_person_Age                    22.00
Delivery_person_Ratings                 4.10
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Below is the code -

```
folder_path = '/drive/My Drive/dataset/train'
file_list = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.txt")
main_dataframe = pd.read_fwf(file_list[0], header=None)
  
for i in range(1,len(file_list)):    
    df = pd.read_fwf(file_list[i], header=None)
    main_dataframe = pd.concat([main_dataframe, df], axis = 0)
  
print(main_dataframe.head(30))
```

**Output:**

```
                              0               1
0                            ID          a123
1            Delivery_person_ID  VADRES03DEL01
2           Delivery_person_Age       24.00
3       Delivery_person_Ratings        4.30
4       Name: 1, dtype: object             NaN
0                            ID          b123
1            Delivery_person_ID  VADRES03DEL02
2           Delivery_person_Age       22.00
3       Delivery_person_Ratings        4.10
4       Name: 2, dtype: object            NaN
```

But I need the dataframe to be listed row wise for each person. For eg, in below format I want -

```
                              ID          Delivery_person_ID  Delivery_person_Age       Delivery_person_Ratings       
                              0  a123                VADRES03DEL01      24.00              4.30                             

                              1  b123                VADRES03DEL02      22.00              4.10
```

Comment: is the dtype: object part actually in the text file?

Comment: correct , it is in text file, like i provided above under sample1.txt and sample2.txt

Comment: just used transpose: main_dataframe = main_dataframe.T

Comment: when i transpose I am getting columns getting split into multiple lines... see my edit above.  How to output all the columns in the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading text file to `pandas dataframe` make it `transform` for each one

```py
folder_path = '/drive/My Drive/dataset/train'
file_list = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.txt")
main_dataframe = pd.read_fwf(file_list[0], header=None).T
  
for i in range(1,len(file_list)):    
    df = pd.read_fwf(file_list[i], header=None).T
    main_dataframe = pd.concat([main_dataframe, df], axis = 0)
  
print(main_dataframe.head(30))
```

**Edit**

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

folder_path = '/drive/My Drive/dataset/train'
file_list = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.txt")


def read_clean_df(file_name) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_fwf(file_name, header=None).T
    df.pop(4)
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df[1:]
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return df


main_dataframe = read_clean_df(file_list[0])

for file_name in file_list[1:]:
    df = read_clean_df(file_list[0])
    main_dataframe = pd.concat([main_dataframe, df], axis=0)

main_dataframe.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(main_dataframe.head(30))
```

Comment: when i transpose I am getting columns getting split into multiple lines... see my edit above.  How to output all the columns in the same line?

Comment: It was in same line only.. Due to console/screen width limit, it shows as multiple line

Comment: @ggcoder look at the updated code

Answer (score 1):

So, the input text file is weird - this code should deal with that

```
# Read in text file
df = pd.read_fwf("./test.txt")
# Remove the "Name: 1, dtype: object"
df = df.drop(df.index[3])
# Transpose it
df = df.T
# Rename the columns correctly
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
# Remove the column names from the data
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
```

An input text file that looks like this:

```
ID                                    a123
Delivery_person_ID             VADRES03DEL01
Delivery_person_Age                    24.00
Delivery_person_Ratings                 4.30
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Would be converted to this:

```
ID   Delivery_person_ID Delivery_person_Age Delivery_person_Ratings
a123      VADRES03DEL01               24.00                    4.30
```

From here, you can do the same for each text file, then do a pd.concat() to merge the new textfile dataframe to the main dataframe, but from your code I can see that you already know how to do this.

Comment: great thanks, let me modify my code and check...